# Como transformar um numpy.array de tamanho 497305 em um menor de 4999 sem adicionar novos elementos no cálculo?

Tags: python, numpy

Estou analisando um áudio e meu modelo de ML do scikit learn gera um array de probabilidades de que certo elemento no array corresponda a uma categoria "A" usada pra treinar o modelo.

Cada elemento do array corresponde a uma probabilidade de uma janela de análise obtida através de várias transformações (FFT, Mel...). Para um áudio de 4998,0487 segundos gera-se um array de probabilidades para 497305 janelas de análise. Meu objetivo é transformar esse array de tamanho 497305 em um de tamanho 4998 ou 4999 com a probabilidade média de cada segundo corresponder à categoria "A" do treino.

Meu objetivo, em suma, é usar a média de 100 janelas pra cada segundo (497305 janelas / 4998,0487 ~= 99,5). Como fazer isso de maneira simples usando numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você precise apenas fazer uma média dos valores obtidos a cada 100, você pode simplesmente fazer uma nova matrix com media de cada 100 pontos.

Pra fazer isso é necessário tomar umas precaucões devido ao número de pontos.
Abaixo segue o código para isso, assumindo um vetor.

```
# a é o nome do seu vetor inicial
step=100  #seu passo 
npoints=a.size  #verifica a quantidade de pontos
if npoints%step : #use este IF pra separar os últimos valores
   usedpoints=npoints-npoints%step
else : #ou apenas copia o número
   usedpoints=npoints   

#aqui eu faco a media e deixo em uma matriz
data_average=numpy.mean(a[:usedpoints].reshape(-1,step),axis=1)
#aqui eu pego a média dos últimos pontos e junta a matriz da média. 
numpy.append(data_average,numpy.mean(a[usedpoints:]))
```